# How to overwrite generic class argument that extends record?

Tags: typescript, inheritance, typescript-generics

I have a `Parent` and `Child` classes. The `Parent` class takes 2 generic arguments: `Result` and `ParentBuilderMap`. `Result` is expected to be some sort of class, while `ParentBuilderMap` is a subset of `Result` with specific interface as a value. Now, my goal is to create subclass that would enforce some specific property to be present on the `ParentBuilderMap`, such that I could enforce to use some custom implementation of the interface for that property.

I tried to overwrite the property with `Omit<A, keyof B> & B`, but that yields an error that states that such type is not assignable to the `ParentBuilderMap`, which I find odd, since it would have the same keys (or more which should be fine).

Here's demo implementation of the above description

```js
type Overwrite<A, B> = Omit<A, keyof B> & B;

interface Builder<Result> {
  build(): Result;
}

class SuperSecretBuilder implements Builder<string> {
  build() {
    return "lorem ipsum";
  }

  secret() {
    return "p4ssw0rd";
  }
}

type BuilderMap<Result> = Partial<Record<keyof Result, Builder<unknown>>>;

class Parent<Result, ParentBuilderMap extends BuilderMap<Result>> {
  doWork<Key extends keyof ParentBuilderMap>(key: Key, cb: () => ParentBuilderMap[Key]) {
    // tbd
  }
}

class Child<
  Result,
  ChildBuilderMap extends Overwrite<BuilderMap<Result>, { value: SuperSecretBuilder }>,
> extends Parent<Result, ChildBuilderMap> {
  doSecretWork() {
    // This method should resolve callback return value to SuperSecretBuilder based on provided key.
    this.doWork("value", () => {
      const builder = new SuperSecretBuilder();

      console.log(builder.secret());

      return builder;
    });
  }
}
```

[And playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gbhATgd0QS2BAPAQQDRQBCAfFALywC2GuBA1hCAPYBmRpAZEQNwBQvaAHaZELAIYBjaIQCuaADYATJFgBKEAM4z5wUgG9eUKACM5SgBQBKAFxR1WnXwC+-CfLEaNUAMozIibwgJRAhgWQVlRCg0SjB5CEoIYS9wpRUNYHRBAHN9QxMzRSsoAyMjEOAZREEoACJ5JhDKaLAtSlq+Ixd8jSCK4tKyiqqa2rAAFk9kAAZERQ78l27QSCJCpABZMTA1TW1dcigABTFEYDQxeV2JRsUsBmY2e32CVMisGUE6QSZkQWIAXxeG4PF4TiFhLsHMACOCkmF1ogtmAoBAAB6YQSKFKI5FQ-YAkr5RRMADqjToWAA0oxURiktioA9WMdTvC3pttsRzA9bDSQAQJMZbMUyKQ4cIOUjtgBtfkAXUsRLKUAA9KqoMBjIpFrxuiDPFAAMIACwiWHyzx0eHypoiUuRdMxjPgSFQGGwDu2+J0xAIeigcEuMggtl8-kCwVCUqgTj9vFI6OdYLZkKtMONZqUXrAeSMJMjFXJiDoA3yRnVUAAKmavIlgCamIooBpG9pmyENEx5AgoBJLvJjJI6FBhtVA8HoMAmD4-EhC9HESYPBBm0wamBEEw4GhlM2HgA6cua2sHknF0u1IPyEO1AiivMqvvrjIFCJIQ6CCDIWcRvqL99ECsIEn2fQQu3iA8GmycxTEAg9eijYArEsECnzHGo4LSRBOjKJxUN1FwgA)

Comment: You have two errors here; which one are you asking about specifically?  One is a constraint satisfaction error (which is probably due to lack of compiler ability to perform abstract analysis of generic conditional types) and the other is an implementation return type error (which is because your generic type might be *narrower* than the constraint, even at the `value` key; not sure why you want it to be generic at all there).  I'd be happy to investigate and try to resolve *one* of these, if you'd clear up the other.

Comment: `Parent` class not accepting a compatible type (in my opinion) is the issue here. As to why I need a generic in the `doWork` method: I want to do some operations on the `Builder` in the `Parent` class. That works fine, since there is `Builder<unknown>` ( from `BuilderMap<Result>`. Now, I have couple sub-classes of the `Parent` class. They all need some concrete implementations of `Builder` on some property in the `BuilderMap`. So the goal of the above is to extract `doSecretWork` into abstract class, such that it can be reused by concrete classes (that should extend `Child` classs).

Comment: Additionally, both `Parent` and `Child` classes (as well as any sub-classes that might follow) are implementing `Builder<Result>`. I omitted this since it would only clutter the view.

Comment: As to why I need generic in the `doWork` method: I want to ensure that builder returned from the callback matches `ParentBuilderMap<Result>`. Without generic I could pass any implementation of `Builder`. The `BuilderMap` even came from such that I could resolve correct `Builder` when `build` method is invoked (that happens in the `Parent` class).

Comment: ① If you're asking about the constraint satisfaction error (under `ChildBuilderMap`) and not the callback error (under `() => {`) then please [edit] the code to resolve the latter error, so it's not a distraction and so this is a [mre] (e.g., just assert `as ChildBuilderMap["value"]` in the return line).  Once you do that, does [this approach](//tsplay.dev/wRPgnm) meet your needs? I'm not sure what `Overwrite` buys you, since if there is already a `value` property in `Result`, weird things can potentially happen. If that helps I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Thanks for putting the time into this question. Indeed your proposed approach is something I ended up with and I think we can close this discussion. Feel free to put is as an answer.